# Why does PNG include NLEN (one's complement of LEN)?

Tags: png, ones-complement

In the [PNG spec](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/PNG/RFC-1951#noncompressed), uncompressed blocks include two pieces of header information:

> `LEN` is the number of data bytes in the block. `NLEN` is the one's complement of `LEN`

Why would the file include the one's complement of a value? How would this be used and/or for what purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than inventing a new compression type for PNG, its authors decided to use an existing industry standard: zlib.

The link you provide does not point to the official PNG specifications at http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/ but only to this part: the DEFLATE compression scheme. `NLEN` is not mentioned in the official specs; it only says the default compression is done according to zlib (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950), and therefore DEFLATE (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).

As to "why": zlib precedes current day high-speed internet connections, and at the time it was invented, private internet communication was still done using audio line modems. Only few institutions could afford dedicated landlines for just data; the rest of the world was connected via dial-up. Due to this, data transmission was highly susceptible to corruption. For simple text documents, a corrupted file might still be usable, but in compressed data literally every single bit counts.

Apart from straight-on data corruption, a dumb (or badly configured) transmission program might try to interpret certain bytes, for instance changing Carriage Return (`0x0D`) into Newline (`0x0A`), which was a common option at the time. "One's complement" is the inversion of every single bit for 0 to 1 and the reverse. If either `LEN` *or* `NLEN` happened to be garbled or changed by the transmission software, then its one's complement would not match anymore.

Effectively, the presence of both `LEN` and `NLEN` doubles the level of protection against transmission errors: if they do not match, there is an error. It adds another layer of error checking over zlib's ADLER32, and PNGs own per-block checksum.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks! Is the idea then that you'd look at `LEN` and `NLEN` and, if they weren't the same, you could assume there was an error in transmission somewhere? Is this something that would have been super obvious to someone in 1995 reading the spec?

Comment: It's a chain of specifications. When working on my own PNG decoder, I worked back from the oldest part – the raw DEFLATE specs. In that sense it's "obvious" as it's "just another part".

Comment: Thanks – I saw it in the `zlib`/`DEFLATE` docs but there's no explanation as to why or how the values are used. Lots of carryover from old tech even today!

Comment: Yep. But unless you plan to re-make zlib from the ground up (in itself a worthwhile exercise -- but no more than that, an *exercise*), you can just use Python's built-in zlib for examining PNGs. If this says something cannot be extracted, it's kinda superfluous to examine whether it's due to a bad Huffmann tree (the DEFLATE part), a wrong bit set in CFINFO or a bad Adler32 (both in zlib), or elsewhere. All you really need is the superstructure of PNG, which is fully described in its own specs. If you are concerned about PNG integrity, use `pngcheck` first.

Comment: Basically yes, I'm building a `zlib` decoder from scratch and want to understand all the pieces, both from an historical and technical standpoint. This was super helpful.